# the difference bewteen function ref and normal ref in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Today I was learning how to use the ref & v-for function with the example below, but I found that it's difficult to understand. So I try a easier way to do the same thing, however the result is not the same. Could anybody please resolve my curiosity ?

example:

```
    <template>
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="(name, i) in names"
          :key="name"
          :ref="(el) => (elements[i] = el)"
        >
          {{ name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
        <!-- my idea -->
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="(name) in names"
          :key="name"
          ref="newElements"
        >
          {{ name }}
       </li>
     </ul>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
    export default {
      setup() {
        const names = ref(['Matt', 'John', 'Jane'])
        const elements = ref([])
        const newElements = ref('')
        const checkSame = function(){
          elements.value === newElements.value
          ? console.log("true")
          : console.log("false");
        }
        onMounted(() => {
          console.log(elements.value) // [li, li ,li]
          console.log(newElements.value) // [li, li ,li]
          checkSame()  // false
        })
        return {
          names,
          elements,
          newElements,
          checkSame 
        }
      },
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [official docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for)

> ..the ref (normal ref) array does not guarantee the same order as the source array.

However with [function ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs) you've more flexibility :

> ...which will be called on each component update and gives you full flexibility on where to store the element reference